# If a woman converted via Orthodox but had no intention and kept no mitzvoth- are her children jewish

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism

A non-Jewish women converted via an Orthodox conversion in order to marry a Jew. At the time of conversion she claimed to accept the mitzvot but did not intend and never kept proper halachot including Kashrut, Shabbos and Taras HaMishpocha- are the children of such a marriage Jews according to Orthodox law?

Comment: Her children are Jewish if she is Jewish. Your question implies that a lack of intent to keep Judaism could preclude proper conversion. Do you have reason to believe it doesn't? Otherwise, the answer is obviously not...

Comment: I feel like we have a question like this elsewhere on this site

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501). Hope to see you around!

Comment: How would you determine her intent? Not fulfilling mitzwot is not the same as never intending to.

Answer (score 1):

If she truly did not intend to observe the torah, her conversion is invalid. It is a well established *Halacha* that *"Kabalat Ol Mitzvos"* (acceptance of the yoke of Mitzvos) is integral to conversion.

"כל הגויים כולם, כשיתגיירו ויקבלו עליהן כל המצוות שבתורה... - הרי הן כישראל לכל דבר" (רמב"ם איסורי ביאה, פרק י"ב, הל י"ז)